# Can't connect kurento from mobile browser using mobile data connection

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, gstreamer, kurento

Working on the `Webrtc` technologies using `Kurento Media Server` as back-end. 
Application working very smoothly on desktop and mobile via [Wifi/Ethernet].

But when I am trying to connect (Mobile) using mobile data connection its not connected. Can you tell me what is issue?

It is a `TURN Server` problem (Now TURN is disable), Even If `TURN Server` is implemented successfully, then we will face issues like `UDP` packet blocking in corporate firewalls and I think `Firefox` and `Chrome` doesn't support `TCP` based `TURN` communication.

Answer (score 1):

It's a websocket problem, most likely. Some companies block those long lived connections. Check if there is any data arriving at your server from the cien when connected through 3G.

My suggestion is to provide an HTTP fallback in those cases. You can enable SockJS support in the Spring-Boot app and in the client very easily.

Comment: I am getting following log when mobile client connected to server through 3G. 

```2016-02-02 16:31:14,469465 24875 [0x00007f18297fa700]    info KurentoWebRtcEndpointImpl WebRtcEndpointImpl.cpp:285 WebRtcEndpointImpl()  stun address xx.xx.xx.xxx```